# How To Transpose List<T> Depending On First Letter

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of strings and i want to pivot it depending on first letter.

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("A1");
lst.Add("A2");
lst.Add("A3");
lst.Add("B1");
lst.Add("B2");
lst.Add("B3");
lst.Add("C1");
lst.Add("C2");
lst.Add("C3");
```

And what i have to do is to create a new matrix that is like following:

```
A  B  C
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
```

Output can be any type of suitable object that i can loop over it.

Any suggestions? or a redirection?

Thanks

Note that A,B,C is not fixed, can be A,B,C,D,E..Z as well. And 1,2,3 can be in any order.

Thanks

Comment: That is a matrix not an array. Do you mean get the numbers linked to each letter, like `{A: [1,2,3]}, {B: [1,3,5]}`?

Comment: Every letter always has only 3 values? letters are always ascending order?

Comment: What do you mean by "transpose"? In your "new array", what there is actually part of the array, and what there (if anything) is just labels for rows and/or columns of the array? Please be more specific. Please also provide a good [mcve] that shows what you're trying to do, along with a precise explanation of what the output should be, given some specific input.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete description. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to create a Lookup with this LINQ expression:

```
var result = lst.Select(x => new {Key = x[0], Value = x.Substring(1)})
    .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

You can then loop over it:

```
foreach (var k in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(k.Key);
    foreach (var val in k)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  " + val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, this is more elegant solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

This transformation is called `pivot` not `transpose`. Transpose just switch the x axis with y-axis.

This will give you a `string[][]` with the desired data :

```
var pivot = lst.Select(x => new
    {
        Column = x[0].ToString(),
        Value = x.Substring(1)
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Column, (k, g) => new[] { k }.Concat(g.Select(x => x.Value)).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```